# How to lock the JFrame's position?

Tags: java, swing, locking, position, jframe

I have a problem with locking the posistion of my `JFrame` on the visible screen. I want to lock the position of the `JFrame` in the screen so that nobody is able to move it or relocate it.

Thanks for your help already.

Answer (score 1):

it is impossible to guarantee that the user can never move a `JFrame`.  That decision is up to the user's OS and window manager.

If it is good enough to remove the frame's title bar and resize handles, which stops the user from using their mouse to move the frame, then do this:

```
jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Comment: actually i created a screen saver but this screen-saver quits the system with Back-Space and so user can drag the window and continue his/her work. i dont want that he or she could move it.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict `JFrame` movement, remove title bar, put your own title bar + closing & minimizing mechanism on it. This is a work around that restrict shifting `JFrame` window with mouse.

Comment: Don't just include a link to the answer, if that page goes away the answer is useless. Also, if it only restricts it to being moved with the mouse, then it doesn't really answer the question.